# Deciphering an handwritten sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

I'm trying to decipher the following handwritten text.

[image]

My best guess is:

> man wird mir immer die Deutung als Automorphismen der formel(?) entstehenden(?) Links(oder Rechts-)Ideale als Richtschnur nehmen müssen.

It could probably translate to something like:

> To me one must take as a guideline the interpretation of the formula-developing left(or right-)ideals as automorphisms.

This is clearly an indecent translation, but it's what I can come to.
Any enlightening idea on words and meanings?

Comment: it's rather "formal" (*formally*) than "formel". Rest looks O.K.

Comment: The word after "man wird" does not contain the letter "i" (as you can see by looking at r"the occurences of an "i" in the rest of the text). Therefore it should not be "mir" - which by the way also does not fit semantically into the sentence. The first letter is probably an "m" or an "n" and the last letter an "r". The second letter remains mysterious. The word "nur" would be appropriate semantically, but I am not really convinced.

Answer (score 3):

> man wird mir immer die Deutung als Automorphismen der formal entstehenden Links(oder Rechts-)Ideale als Richtschnur nehmen müssen.
>
> > To me one must take as a guideline the interpretation [of whatever?] as automorphisms  of the formally resulting left (or right) ideals.

Note that the sentence leaves open what is supposed to be interpreted ("gedeutet") as automorphisms.